# Submit a standard HTML form with React input fields

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, http

Sometimes I just want to submit a "normal" form, but have the input fields in React (of styling reasons).

But the form doesn't seem to "see" the values of the input fields when submitting.

```
<form action="comments" method="post">
  <label>
    Name:
    <input
      className={styles.input}
      defaultValue="Bob"
      type="text"
      ref={this.input} />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Is there a way to accomplish something like the above, i.e. posting a form without having to create an `onSubmit` event handler that referes to every single field in the form?

Ps. I'm aware that the default React way is to include `state`, but that increases the boilerplate code even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use name tag in your input

e.g.

```
<input name="comment" type="text" defaultValue="Bob"/>
```